# When is a 'gerund' supposed to be preceded by a possessive adjective/determiner?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives, gerunds, register, possessive-determiners

I assume that the following sentences are all acceptable:

> - He resents **your** being more popular than he is.
> - Most of the members paid their dues without **my** asking them.
> - They objected to the youngest **girl’s** being given the command position.
> - What do you think about **his** buying such an expensive car?
> - We were all sorry about **Jane’s** losing her parents like that.

I’m still getting used to this “possessive with 'gerund' ” structure. It sounded so weird to me at first.

Is this structure used in both formal and informal contexts, both oral and written alike? Are there any alternative structures that result in the same meaning and are more frequently used?

(Examples taken from [Grammar Tips: Possessives Precede Gerunds](http://grammartips.homestead.com/possessivewithgerund.html))

Comment: It's one variant, and falutes slightly higher, but with pronouns there are many idioms. Gerund clauses have two complementizers: the normal `Acc`-_ing_ complementizer (*without **him** telling me*), and the `Poss`-_ing_ complementizer (*without **his** telling me*). Both are correct, both are common, but `Acc`-_ing_ is somewhat more common in practice.

Comment: @John Lawler  Professor Lawler, I wasn't able to find "falute" as a verb in M-W U or in other dictionaries. It might be in the OED. Your meaning here seems to be "being pretentious," but I'd appreciate your take on it.

Comment: Look up "high-faluting" and apply a morphological filter.

Comment: @JohnLawler: help! I cannot understand why my edit to the title of the post (replacing 'pronoun' with 'adjective or determiner') was rejected!

Comment: @JohnLawler As far as the UK is concerned, the "poss *-ing* variety (albeit perhaps less common) is certainly associated with a better educated and more erudite individual. For that reason I would always encourage any young person to prefer it to the alternative. Though I certainly use both forms myself, and the choice of which, as with many expressions, could well depend on whom I am talking to.

Comment: @WS2 being perceived as "better educated and more erudite" is *not always* desirable for any given linguistic intercourse. If one's interlocutors are speaking in  basilect, use of highfalutin grammar may not serve your communications purpose. The advice I would give is to choose the form that best matches the formality level of the discourse.

Comment: @nohat I think I made that point in my comment. Unfortunately one cannot discuss the use of the English language without trespassing into the minefield of social class. Only last night I heard a radio interview with Nell Dunn, author of such as *Up the Junction* and *Poor Cow*. She and others, such as Dennis Potter,  writing in the 1960s explored this in depth.

Comment: @WS2 As is often the case, I strongly disagree. Although I'm with nohat about adjusting register judiciously (ie being open to the use of either variant where both are possible), there are times when the Poss-ing and the Acc-ing have different meanings. "She didn't like his singing" means that the rendition was not her favourite music while "She didn't like him singing" might mean that she considered it unwise for a person in the Witness Protection Scheme to appear on stage.

Comment: The last seems a fair point. But I'm still not clear what it is that you "stronly disagree" with. And I'm not sure if the way you are using "his singing" is strictly an example of what is under discussion here. "She didn't like his singing but enjoyed his dancing" is one thing.  But I think we are talking here, more about "Bearing in mind the sad news that had just been delivered, she didn't like his singing". They seem two quite different things to me. And I thought we were discussing the latter.  
WS2

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I guess the point I'm making is that "singing" is not a good example - since "singing" has a well-established noun status already - which is how you are using it. It's rather different if we say "She didn't like his helping himself to the sherry trifle".

Comment: I'd say that 'As far as the UK is concerned, the "poss -ing variety (albeit perhaps less common) is certainly associated with a better educated and more erudite individual. _For that reason I would **always** encourage any young person to prefer it to the alternative._ is encouraging all young people to sound at times pompous / rarefied. "What do you think about Jane's coming too?"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No. I said "prefer it". And the choice of which I use "depends on who I'm talking to".  You may be having difficulty finding a suitable pigeon-hole in which to put me, but I spent my childhood in rural Norfolk - where the people around me spoke something far removed from received English. Indeed I went to grammar school believing that the past tense of "snow" was "snew". And there are probably still people around with whom I would use "snew". But I would encourage a young person to say "snowed".  How is the possesive gerund any different.

Comment: @WS2 Come on. "I would always encourage any young person to prefer it to the alternative" is what you wrote.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So? You really will have to begin articulating your objections succinctly. What is the point you are making?

Comment: @WS2 "I would always encourage any young person to prefer it to the alternative" is a bald statement; moderating it later on does not change this but merely confuses. It's bad advice, because (a) sometimes the POSS-ing gives a meaning not intended and the ACC-ing is the only correct choice and (b) even where not incorrect from a semantic perspective, the use of the ACC-ing often sounds grandiloquent (nohat puts this better).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth As Queen Gertrude might have put it (*Hamlet*) - thou protesteth too much. But by all means flag it as in need of moderator intervention - should it be causing you a loss of sleep.

Comment: @WS2 The snag is that people come here expecting advice about best practice. Both nohat and myself have stated clearly that care should be taken in avoiding pretentious-sounding alternatives. This relates to G Pullum's "If there's someone at the door and when you ask 'Who is it?' they answer 'It is I', steer clear of them' [paraphrased].

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nohat in his excellent answer (which I upvoted) uses the terms *more formal*, and *less stuffy* - which I certainly agree with. Contrary to what you say he has not used the term *pretentious-sounding* - only you have used that.

Comment: @WS2 From [Passmore's thesis comparing/contrasting the POSS-ING and ACC-ING structures](https://scholarship.tricolib.brynmawr.edu/bitstream/handle/10066/10324/Passmore_thesis_2004.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y): << Hudson describes (5a) as "forced and formal" in British English (2003: 603),
while many Americans would actually prefer the  POSS-ING (5a) to the ACC-ING (5b) structures:
(5) a. _John's knowing the answer surprised us._
b. _John knowing the answer surprised us._ >> The relevant definition of 'forced' from Lexico is 'affected or unnatural'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh dear! I have no idea who in the world Hudson is, nor how I got to my advanced age without anyone ever previously pointing out to me that my choice of language was "forced", "affected"  or "unnatural"? I am deeply humbled!

Comment: @WS2 [Richard Hudson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Hudson_(linguist)) (Wikipedia), whose linguistic credentials obviously outrank mine. At least.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well the relevant passage in Passmore is: *(2003: 581). Hudson does not provide much evidence to support a difference between 
British and American English; if there is a difference, it is probably not very large. 
However, Hudson describes (5a) as "forced and formal" in British English (2003: 603), 
while many Americans would actuaUy prefer the POSS-ING (Sa) to the ACC-ING (5b):* So in American it appears acceptable, but "forced and formal" (and hence affected) in British. Yet there is little evidence to support a difference between the two!

Comment: And on that basis you have deduced my position where I have come down on the American side of a dichotomy which is "probably not very large" as "affected or unnatural".  You probably need to take a walk in the fresh air for a few minutes and have a think.

Comment: It's not something that most people are consistent about. If you actually investigate, like sociolinguists do, you find that individuals sometimes use one and sometimes the other, and their opinions about what they say and how they "always say it" are extremely unreliable. Every individual is unique in their habits, and every individual is a member of several groups whose speech they can imitate.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

When I first heard about this usage in a grammar lesson in middle school, it sounded weird to me, too. As in the linked page in your answer, my teacher taught us that using possessive pronouns (also known as *genitives*) is the only grammatical way to mark subjects of gerund clauses. While that way is more traditional and formal, using object pronouns (*accusatives*) is also quite common.

In chapter 14, section 4.3, of the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, entitled “Non-finite and verbless clauses”, the main thrust lays waste to the traditional distinction between gerund clauses and present participle clauses, by arguing they all belong to a single inflectional category; namely, gerund-participles. However, there is a paragraph explaining the use of genitives with gerunds:

> There is one respect in which ‘gerund’ and ‘present participle’ clauses differ in their internal form: with ‘gerunds’ the subject may take genitive case, with plain or accusative case a less formal alternant, but with ‘present participles’ the genitive is impossible and pronouns with a nominative–accusative contrast appear in nominative case, with accusative an alternant restricted to informal style. Compare then:
>   [39]  i. *She resented **his/him/*he** being invited to open the debate.*
>            ii. *We appointed Max, **he/him/*his** being much the best qualified of the candidates.*

In other words, gerunds (as in example 39i) can take either the genitive (*his*) or the accusative (*him*) as subject, with genitive being more formal and accusative less formal. The nominative (*he*) is not possible as the subject of a gerund.

In participial clauses with a subject (as in example 39ii), there is a similar situation: both the nominative (*he*) and accusative (*him*) are possible, again with accusative being less formal, but the genitive (*his*) is not possible.

The page of “grammar tips” linked in the question confuses informal style with incorrect grammar, a common problem in grammar advice. The versions of the examples with accusative instead of genitive (e.g. *What do you think about **him** buying such an expensive car?*) are perfectly grammatical and simply a less stuffy style.

You will find many examples of gerunds with accusative subject—even in formal academic writing—so you should feel free to use whichever of the two formulations seems natural.

Comment: Great explanation! I had wondered about this too. Btw, do you agree with [Steve](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/gerund-preceded-by-possessive-pronoun-e-g-he-resents-your-being-more-popular-t/2630#2630) about examples 3 and 5?

Comment: There actually can be cases where the two forms are semantically distinct.  "I hate John driving" means that you hate the idea of John driving, while "I hate John's driving" means that you hate John's style of driving.  Just an interesting added factoid — I don't really have a good analysis of it.

Comment: @Jonik, the only one where I might use the genitive form would be #1. All the rest I would almost certainly use the accusative with. On editing, though, I might change them to genitive. Old habits inculcated by strict teachers die hard.

Comment: I will throw in a link to the wonderfully informative Language Log entry that was published two weeks after this question (and your answer) had been posted: [Possessive with gerund: Tragic loss or good riddance?](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2637)

Comment: You might like [this reference](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2641), which follows up to @RegDwigнt's reference with a bit of corpus analytics.

Comment: *stuffy style*? What do you think about *what do you think about () buying such an expensive car*?

Comment: @vectory not sure what your question is, but if you can clarify I'd be happy to explain what I mean.

Comment: I'm asking whether you think your version is less stuffy than that without the pronoun. For sake of the argument there is no semantic difference, because the answer could still go, "I think, he's ... for doing it".

Answer (score 31):

It is perhaps worth adding the contrast identified in the ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’:

> When the possessive alternative is used, it focuses attention on the
>   action described in the ‘-ing’ clause. In contrast the regular Noun
>   Phrase form puts more emphasis on the person doing the action.

Comment: +1 I always thought this *was* the primary *distinction*, not an additional feature -- that there indeed is a distinction.

Comment: @Kris: For it to be a *primary* distinction would require that most competent speakers normally make that distinction consciously, which I think is highly unlikely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As I have commented to John Lawler, I believe (in the UK, as with so many things) it boils down to who you are talking to. If it's a professor in the history department the possessive would apply. If it's the bloke sitting next to me at a football match the accusative would undoubtedly come out first.

Comment: @WS2: As John so charmingly puts it, *[the possessive] **falutes** slightly higher.* So I *might* make the same distinction as you for the same reason, but to be honest I'd be as likely to deliberately flout that "convention" *just because I can.* There's no danger of being misunderstood, unless you include the possibility that the history professor might mistakenly suppose I don't know how to use English properly (in which case I'd be gleefully thinking *Bring it on! You ignorant pedant!*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  This may not be the best example, since it is not especially incorrect to use the "lower faluting" alternative. However no one in Britain is liberated to the extent that they are as happy speaking to a professor in the same way they would speak to Alf Garnet and (importantly) vice-versa - consciously or unconsciously. The smart thing is to be able to be all things to all people.

Comment: @WS2: There's clearly an implication from your *not **especially** incorrect* that you genuinely feel there's at least *some* degree of possible "incorrectness" in this area. Whilst I accept John's "high falutin'" distinction without question, and I'm fully prepared to accept that Barrie's distinction *could* apply with some exceptionally Lit-Crit-minded speakers (definitely with some literary *writers*), I give no credence whatsoever to the idea that either form is more *syntactically* correct. It's just petty pedantic one-upmanship for those who want to play that particular game.

Comment: ...I always think "good" use of language is that which maximises the chance of the other person understanding exactly what you're trying to convey, not that which more closely adheres to often-outdated syntax rules.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are in conversation here with someone, the story of whose youth was juxtaposing the Norfolk dialect spoken at home and in the village, with that of my bourgeois peers at grammar school in Norwich. I could not possibly have progressed into professional life had I stuck with the broad Norfolk. Having said all that I do think it would be a pity if UK English just became dumbed down to a flat estuary format. There is a certain elegance in such things as using the possessive with the gerund, where personally I would find it a pity if it were lost entirely.

Comment: @WS2: Indeed - and I'm certainly not suggesting it would be good to discard *either* of the alternatives under consideration here. And in general I agree with your point that it's good to be able to be all things to all people (so if you know your interlocutor "expects" a certain register that you can comfortably reproduce, you should probably do so). But because I think such expectations often reflect unwarranted prejudice, sometimes I can't help flouting the "register matching" principle just to undermine those expectations (if I can afford to be negatively but wrongly assessed! :)

Comment: ...apropos which, I was rather charmed yesterday to see a motorway gantry sign warning me not to use my mobile ***whilst*** driving. It's not that I have a strong preference one way or the other with ***while / whilst***, but I like the fact that I can choose which to use in most contexts. And while I'm aware some people might think ***whilst*** is a bit "dated" (or even "dialectal, rustic"), I reckon to some *other* people it actually *falutes higher,* to further leverage John's excellent description.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OED has some interesting material on the etymology of ***highfalutin*** (as they have chosen to spell it). The below is but a small extract.

*1836   U.S. Songster 216,   I play upon de cymbal an I makes de handsome sound, I's a high feluting nigger dat dey calls Jim Brown.
Other suggestions include influence from U.S. English †high-saluting performing the regulation military salute precisely, apparently used (in military slang) in a derogatory manner to refer to men who were perceived to be trying to ingratiate themselves with officers (early 19th cent.*

Answer (score 7):

Just to comment on common usage (in British English, at least):

Examples 1, 2 and 4, which use possessive pronouns, look OK, but are somewhat formal. I'd be more likely to use the accusative forms, namely:

> He resents *you* being more popular than he is.
>
> Most of the members paid their dues without *me* asking them.
>
> What do you think about *him* buying such an expensive car?

I can believe that examples 3 and 5, which use nouns, may be grammatically correct, but they look wrong, and I do not recall seeing or hearing that particular construction used. I would drop the "-'s" in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my "common usage" (and non-formal) take:

- He resents your being more popular than he is. (either your-you)
- Most of the members paid their dues without my asking them. (my preferred)
- They objected to the youngest girl's being given the command
  position. (girl only)
- What do you think about his buying such an expensive car? (either his-him)
- We were all sorry about Jane's losing her parents like that. (Jane only)

I'm not an expert on all usage, but these are based on my "formality-detector" radar working. Pronouns are easier to work with - if the possessive of the gerund is called for ("Jane's", etc) it needs to be treated with some care, so as to not sound overly correct.

Comment: Why only young girl , but not Young girl’s in third sentence

Answer (score -1):

By using a direct object and not possessive pronoun, the gerundive (adjectival) clauses describe the subject of the sentence, which is not what you intend to do in your examples.

For example, these sentences have a completely different meaning than your original ones (punctuation and word order changed to illustrate this):

> - He [e.g., Joe] resents **you**, [Joe] being more popular than he [e.g., Bob] is.
> - Most of the members, asking them, paid their dues without **me**.
> - They, being given the command position, objected to the youngest **girl**.
> - What do you, buying such an expensive car, think about **him**?
> - We, losing her parents like that, were all sorry about **Jane**.

Comment: It's been largely addressed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94235/his-parents-dream-of-him-achieving-a-cambridge-degree-what-is-the-funct/94273#94273). I didn't realise there had been a precursor. The ACC-ing v POSS-ing issue has received _a lot_ of coverage.