# What is the correct form of a gerund?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, gerunds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive pronoun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-pronoun) 
> [“Me being” versus “my being”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31437/me-being-versus-my-being)
> [Usage of the gerund preceded by the possessive pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6756/usage-of-the-gerund-preceded-by-the-possessive-pronoun)

I don't really know what to call it but basically there are two forms that I have seen across different texts:

> *My* being here obviously upsets him.
>
> *Me* being here obviously upsets him.

---

> *My* taking interest in her research has had fantastic effects.
>
> *Me* taking interest in her research has had fantastic effects.

---

> *Your* coming here is quite disturbing
>
> *You* coming here is quite disturbing

---

> Please forgive *my* being aggressive.
>
> Please forgive *me* being aggressive.

I think I must have seen the latter more often but in my head the former makes more sense.

Comment: The word you want for what you call a 'verb-noun' is a [Gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)

Comment: See the first question this has been closed as a duplicate of for a [comprehensive answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2628/300) by one of our linguists.

Answer (score 10):

If you precede the *-ing* form of the verb with a possessive determiner such as *my*, you emphasise the action. If you precede it with a personal pronoun such as *me*, you emphasise the person who is performing the action. I have posted about it [on my former blog](http://grammarforgrownups.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/ing-form-verb-or-noun/). For something more authoritative, you can read the [British linguist David Crystal on the subject](http://david-crystal.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/on-memy-being-right.html).

Comment: Trust David Crystal. He knows what he's talking about.

Comment: Oh I see, so really you can use both but they have slightly different meanings?

Comment: N.B. There is a slight problem with the argument (as exposed by Crystal) that "my" 'highlights the noun phrase', though: the gerund would still be modified by an adverb, not an adjective.

Answer (score 3):

The former 'makes more sense' according to a piece of made-up logic that isn't the same logic by which the language operates. It has become a written convention used by people who subscribe to that logic. So if you write "My being here..." instead of "Me being here...", you will be following an arbitrary convention that lots of people follow and few people will accuse you of using an "incorrect" form.

But remember: the language doesn't owe you any guarantee of 'making sense' by some logic that you've made up. The reason that you hear the latter forms more often is probably because according to the system by which the actual *language* operates, those are the natural forms. There's nothing necessarily wrong in using natural language rather than following an arbitrary convention based on fallacy.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I found this quite interesting too: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+being+here%2Cme+being+here&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=20 You can see how "me" is slowly increasing it's frequency over "my".