# "If you don't mind me asking" or "If you don't mind my asking"?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Which one is more appropriate - "If you don't mind me asking" or "If you don't mind my asking"?

I always thought that it was "If you don't mind me asking", but I recently heard "If you don't mind my asking" (more precisely, whilst watching *True Detective*, I heard "If you don't mind me asking" but the subtitles read "If you don't mind my asking").

Now, the latter makes sense if "asking" is referred to as a noun, but it sounds a little twisted.

Which one is the right one?

Thanks

Comment: Both are fine - one excuses the person, the other excuses the question.

Comment: @Lawrence: Do you mean that in the first one I am asking the other person to excuse me for asking a question, and in the second one I am asking the other person to excuse me for the specific contents of the question?

Comment: I believe there is no difference in meaning, if only in register.

Comment: @barakmanos For the first, yes. For the second, you're asking that the interruption be excused (i.e. something along the lines of *sorry for the inconvenience of having to listen to my question*).

Comment: This is a good question...   Not only have I heard both, I've *used* both - probably without realizing it.  Since my mom is from New England and my dad is from New York, when I notice these oddities in my own speech, I chalk it up to "regional differences". (US)

Comment: They have the same meaning; the difference is one of style, with genitive "my" being formal and the more widely used "me" being informal.

Comment: Related question, [What is the correct form of a gerund?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70488/what-is-the-correct-form-of-a-gerund/70489#70489). It would be very helpful for you to read the second link in the first answer of the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may say either one, though the meaning would slightly differ.

- *"Me asking"* is more protocolar with deference for your interlocutor ; it's the usual version.
- *"My asking"* - which is also OK - is just excusing *your* question, not your person expressing it. (I guess we would not use it before a king, even if we don't care of royalty as in the White House & Senate we hear "excuse my asking" in comittee or from the press. In Courts, the bench often shoots "my asking".)

Comment: OK, I'll have to translate "protocolar", "deference" and "interlocutor" first...

Comment: You don't need a translator but an english dictionary :)

Comment: OK, thanks, I'm still trying to figure out the other answers posted as suggestions.

Comment: OK only if you're serious (I thought you were joking) : protocolar - formal ; interlocutor - the one you talk ; deference - respect

Comment: OK ! sorry Barak

Comment: Is 'english' intentional, or a typo like 'though the meaning would slightly differs'?

Comment: You'd deserve a "ya" dear Edwin, but it is not