# Is "Forgive my being late" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds

Is it grammatically correct to write "forgive my being late to this discussion" as an alternative to "sorry that I'm late to this discussion"?

Comment: Related: [Gerund preceded by possessive pronoun (e.g. “He resents your being more popular than he is”)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/gerund-preceded-by-possessive-pronoun-e-g-he-resents-your-being-more-popular-t), complete with an excellent answer and a link to Language Log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example

> Forgive my being late ...

is a typical example of a grammatical feature known as a *gerund*:

> **gerund** |ˈjerənd|
>   *noun* Grammar
>   a form that is derived from a verb but that functions as a noun, in English ending in *-ing*, e.g., *asking* in *do you mind my asking you?*. [NOAD]

So, yes, that is a perfectly grammatical expression.

Answer (score 2):

I'd change *to* to *for*, but otherwise it seems quite correct to me.

> Forgive my being late for this discussion

Answer (score 1):

Any of the following should be acceptable:
 - Forgive my being late
 - Forgive **me for being** late
 - Forgive my late arrival

Answer (score 0):

Probably most speakers wouldn't find your first version is ungrammatical as such, but it's certainly not the most common way of expressing what you want to say. If have a look, for example, at [ngram data for "forgive my being" vs "forgive me for being"](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=forgive%20my%20being,forgive%20me%20for%20being&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), you'll see that the latter version is several times more common.