# Please explain the grammar behind these sentences

Tags: grammar

I have used these kinds of sentences in talking and writing for so long without really knowing the grammar behind them:

> This resulted in **my getting** late
>
> It's unfortunate that even after **his trying** to convince her, she didn't agree
>
> He couldn't resist himself despite **my warning** him

Comment: Well, the first one is incorrect. It should be my _being_ late.

Comment: It's a gerund. See [Use of gerund and possessive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6756/usage-of-the-gerund-preceded-by-the-possessive-pronoun)

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/33825/17956

Answer (score 4):

In your examples, the *-ing* forms are seen as nouns requiring possessive determiners, such as *my* or *his*. They can, however, also be seen as non-finite verbs, requiring the accusative forms of personal pronouns, such as *me* or *him*.

The choice depends on the emphasis which the speaker or writer wants to give. The ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’ explains that:

> . . . when the possessive alternative is used, it focuses attention on
>   the action described in the *–ing* clause. In contrast [the
>   non-possessive] form puts more emphasis on the person doing the
>   action.

‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’ makes the additional point that:

> The choice of the possessive *my* [for example] makes the sentence
>   rather formal, while the use of the object pronoun *me* is acceptable in
>   most everyday kinds of writing.

Answer (score 0):

Please read up on the wonderful realm of [participles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle).

Participles - turning a verb into an entity or entity descriptor.

Examples of participles you are already familiar with

- painting, from the verb paint. e.g.

  - I wish to buy this painting.
- building

  - Are you contributing to the school building fund?
  - Before coming to New York, I had never seen such density of high-rise buildings.
- running

  - We plan to contribute substantially to her running (in the marathon).
  - We plan to contribute significantly to her painting.
- painted

  - their painted faces adorned the football stadium
- convicted

  - the convicted should not be allowed to hold office

Just think of it this way, if you would accept `painting` or `building` as participles, then you could accept any participle.

- My running late to the office could cost me my job.
- I cannot tolerate his smoking (in the office).
- I cannot tolerate his painting.