# Use of possessive or object pronoun

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns, possessives, objects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive pronoun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-pronoun)

> - 1. Do you mind *me* smoking?
>   2. Do you mind *my* smoking?
> - 1. There's little chance of *you* getting a sunburn.
>   2. There's little chance of *your* getting a sunburn.

I was taught in school to use the latter of each pair, though have heard the former in daily life. Which is correct, or does it matter?

Comment: I was taught in school to answer "Do you mind me smoking?" with "Not at all, burst into flames if you like."