# Is "We look forward to your spending time with us" a proper use of "your"?

Tags: grammaticality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive pronoun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-pronoun)

The phrase “We look forward to your spending time with us” is common in invites in my industry but it feels like “all your base are belong to us” to me. `:-P`

Is it proper English?

Comment: I say drop the 'R'.

Comment: To me it is correct, meaning "your action of spending time". I wouldn't change it.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2628/300) to the question I'm closing this as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing grammatically wrong with *your* in OP's example (but the comparison should be to [all your base **are** belong to us](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all-your-base-are-belong-to-us)! :). Consider...

> We look forward to your arrival
>
> We look forward to you arriving

...where obviously both are fine. In the first case we've got a noun, and in the second it's a gerund. We can substitute *spending time with us* in either of those roles, so both *your* and *you* are grammatically valid. The reason OP often sees *your* on invitations, etc., is simply that it's rather more formal in tone, and thus seems more appropriate to that context.