# What is the name of the grammar structure of the words in the sentences below

Tags: meaning

What is the name of the grammar structure for sentences or expressions in the examples below?

Your ***coming*** here is always a pleasure!!

Your ***talking*** to her made all the difference !!

In these sentences the expressions : coming and talking are what? Verb , noun etc ?

Comment: English verb forms ending in *-ing* and used as nouns are *gerunds*.

Comment: Addressed and answered at ["Because of our doing something ..." - Is this correct English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77775/because-of-our-doing-something-is-this-correct-english) and earlier threads.

Answer (score 1):

They're verbs.

Notice how you can't say those sentences with "the":

"*The coming here..."

"*The talking to her..."

And you definitely can't use "the" and still make it about this "You":

"*The coming of you here..."

"*The talking to her by you..."

But you can say things like:

"That you come here..." or

"That you talked to her..." 

or

"It is always a pleasure when you come here" or

"It made all the difference that you talked to her"

This seems to be evidence that these are not gerunds, but deep-structure verbs which have been stuck in the subject position because there's nothing else to be there. This is called a transformation, I suggest looking up "passive sentence transformation" to learn more about them.

A gerund works like:

"The ending was great"

or

"The talking was non-stop"

Another examples:

"Coming here was horrible"
Even though "coming here" is in the subject position, it's a verb with an object! Nouns can't have objects like that, no matter what. And, as we expect:

"*The coming here..." just doesn't sound right.

Hope that works for ya!

Answer (score 0):

Each is preceded by a determiner, and each is the subject of a clause. Together that makes them nouns.