# "...his parents' dream of *him* achieving a Cambridge degree." What is the function of "him" here?

Tags: gerunds, personal-pronouns, present-participles, ing, possessive-vs-oblique

I have a problem analysing this sentence from the point of finite/nonfinite clauses, clause elements and their functions:

> He does not want to destroy his parents' **dream of him achieving a Cambridge degree**.

I am especially interested in the: *dream of him achieving a Cambridge degree.*

I know that 'achieving a Cambridge degree' is a non-finite *-ing* participle clause. However what is its function? And what is the function of 'of him'? Is it a postmodification?

Answer (score 15):

As for the pronoun, both *him* and *his* -- respectively, the ACC-*ing* complementizer and the POSS-*ing* complementizer, as they're called in the trade -- are acceptable as the subject of the gerund complement clause.

POSS-*ing* is slightly more formal and more often written, and may be claimed to be "more grammatical" or "the only correct choice" or something of the sort. But it's your choice, really.

As for the parse, there are 3 clauses, because there are three verbs: *want, destroy, achieve*

There is, as usual, one main clause (`S₀`)

- `S₀` = *He does not want `S₁`*

with an [A-Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) infinitive complement clause `S₁`as the direct object of *want*:

- `S₁` = *[for him] to destroy his parents' dream of `S₂`*

and a [gerund](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html) [complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html) `S₂` as the object of the preposition *of*:

- `S₂` = *his/him achieving a Cambridge degree.*

Comment: Is it conceivable that *dream of* could be parsed as a nominalized phrasal verb, as might be suggested by "**I > my** dream of Jeannie with the light brown hair"?

Comment: Yes, but a really deep parse like that would involve a lot more transformations. And specifications and boundary conditions for them. [Jim McCawley](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/McCawley-Lg.pdf) used to call stuff like that "remnants of deceased clauses". It's like dissecting a skeleton, in the sense that things that are no longer there can't be sensed -- except from the inside, by the speaker, and everybody's different inside.

Comment: *de mortuis nil*  I guess. I started on an answer, but when it got to 800 words gave up!

Comment: It's been done; it was a stock-in-trade for Generative Semantics, which is the theory I was trained in. Nowadays I'm not very doctrinaire, but I'll allow that the closer the parse is to the logical tree, the better I like it.

Comment: Is *achieving* always a "gerund" here, regardless of whether it's preceded by a possessive form? There seems to be some difference in exactly how it can be "modified", in that I can (just about) go along with ***his** achieving **of** a Cambridge degree*, but that doesn't work at all for me with  ***him** achieving **of** a Cambridge degree*.

Comment: If it has a direct object, as _achieving_ does in the example, then it is indeed a gerund. That's one of the tests. If it were _his achieving of a Cambridge degree_ -- or better yet, _the achieving of_ -- then it's a noun and not a gerund. Gerunds are verbs, not nouns; they are the heads of noun clauses often enough, however.

Comment: @JohnLawler If it's not a trade secret, where can one find information on what 'ACC-ing' and 'POSS-ing' mean?

Comment: They stand for "Accusative plus -_ing_" and "Possessive plus -_ing_", respectively. They are the two varieties of gerund complementizer in English; one uses a bare noun or pronoun (the "accusative", i.e, uninflected, form) as the subject, and the other uses the possessive form for the subject. There's very little difference between them, and so people argue about which one is correct, believing only one can be. Here's [an undergraduate thesis about the difference](https://www.swarthmore.edu/sites/default/files/assets/documents/linguistics/2004_passmore_kara.pdf), which includes lots of data.

Answer (score 8):

The ACC-ing structure may be more appropriate than the POSS-ing structure on occasion, and vice versa.

*We watched him leaving the building to see if he remembered to lock up.*

*We expected his leaving the company to take place long before it actually did.*

The variant with *him* focuses more on the person, the variant with *his* more on the event. In the above two examples, this strongly suggests, or dictates in the second case, which variant should be used. In the original, I think him (more personal) just shades it. Either is grammatical, though the POSS-ing option is more formal and will often sound pretentious in many registers.

.................

A member mentioned the fact that some educational establishments regarded the ACC-ing construction as ungrammatical in the fairly recent past. The only historical treatment I've found is from [Nonfinite Structures in Theory and Change By D. Gary Miller](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RPWD1aSJc0cC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=ACC-ing+and+POSS-ing+history+century&source=bl&ots=9EjJRaDQkw&sig=Qk0YIUERT2RTn-ZHoChZNqIt32U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMmf_CjZvZAhUmJMAKHclAASMQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=ACC-ing%20and%20POSS-ing%20history%20century&f=false), which includes

> Around [1400], NOM-ing (replaced by ACC-ing in about 1900) split off
> from POSS-ing....

This implies that school grammars of the mid-20th Century which forbade the ACC-ing structure might be seen as hyperprescriptivist. Which comes as little surprise.

Comment: _Watch_ is an atypical verb, like all sense verbs; note that a bare infinitive is equally good with _him_ if _watch_ is the verb. The second sentence is rather strange; I would expect _to take place_ or _to occur_ as the predicate, instead of _be_, and _long before_ instead of _far before_.

Comment: Yep - the sneaking up of teatime on one doesn't encourage the formulation of well-considered examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That is really clear and helpful - _him_ focuses on the person; _his_ on the event.

Answer (score 2):

You’re on the right lines in thinking in terms of postmodification. The whole of *of him achieving a Cambridge degree* postmodifies the noun *dream* in that it answers the question ‘What kind of dream?’ The dream is about *him* doing something, the something being *achieving a Cambridge degree*.

Answer (score 0):

"Him achieving" is common, but "his achieving" is grammatically preferred and simpler to explain. The preposition "of" goes with "achieving," which functions as a gerund (-ing verb used as a noun), not a participle.

Comment: You need to add a reference supporting your claim that ' "his achieving" is grammatically preferred'. I agree with John Lawler that 'both _him_ and _his_ ... are acceptable ...'.