# entailed him / his being - use of pronoun vs possessive determiner

Tags: personal-pronouns

> The position entailed him/his being in Chicago most of the time.
>   The bonuses were based on him/his reaching the quota.
>   It had nothing to do with him/his being privy to the information.
>   His fondness for sports resulted in him/his assuming that position.

In the above sentences which one is grammatically correct, *him* or *his*, and why?

Comment: In almost all cases, **both** the `ACC`_-ing him_ **and** the `POSS`_-ing his_ are correct for [gerund complement clauses](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/94272/15299). It's a "speaker's choice" situation; there is no meaning difference.

Comment: This question has been raised several times on ELU, [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2625/24489) for instance, as well as the question John Lawler links.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms of each sentence are both grammatical and in common use. Verbs ending in -ing are generally *present participle* tense, and you can use either the possessive form or the subject form of the pronoun.

If you changed the verb to the infinitive (*to verb*) tense, you would need to treat the pronoun as the corresponding subject to that verb.
This is easy in the first case: 
The position entailed him to be in Chicago most of the time.
It's more difficult in the second sentence:
The bonuses required him to reach the quota.
It's impractical to so with the third and fourth sentences.

In addition, I would recommend avoiding the phrase "assume/assuming the/that position" where possible, as many associate that wording with corporal punishment.

Comment: Right. The predicates in sentences 3 and 4 can take gerund, but can't take infinitive complements, while the predicates in sentences 1 and 2 can take either gerund or infinitive complements.