# Correctness of "of my sending the picture"

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, gerund-phrases

Is this sentence correct?

> I don’t think Linda would have approved **of my  sending the picture**; but I did it anyway.

Specifically, is *of my sending the picture* correct?

Comment: Yes, but _of my sending the picture_ is not a constituent; _of_ goes with _approve_ to form a transitive verb. The gerund clause _my sending the picture_ is the direct object of _approve of_.

Comment: _My sending the picture_ is grammatical, and falutes slightly higher, but with pronouns there are many idioms. Gerund clauses have two complementizers: the normal `Acc`-_ing_ complementizer (_without him telling me_), and the `Poss`-_ing_ complementizer (_without his telling me_). Both are correct, both are common, but Acc-ing is somewhat more common in practice.

Comment: Also answered at [Analysing clause elements and their function](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94235/analysing-clause-elements-and-their-function)