# Possessive + gerund + object pronoun

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I'm reading *The Great Gatsb*y and there's one part when *Tom Buchanan* is arguing by phone with *George Wilson* about a car, and *Tom* says the next:

> Very well, then, I won't sell you the car at all ... I'm under no
>   obligations to you at all ... and as for your bothering me about it at
>   lunch time, I won't stand that at all!

the part:

> [...] and as for your bothering me [...]

has a structure like:

```
possessive adjective + gerund + object pronoun
```

I had never seen such a construction, so my question is:
Is there something elided in the sentence, and what's the meaning of the sentence?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The analagous _his/him achieving a Cambridge degree_ is covered at [Analysing clause elements and their function](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94235/analysing-clause-elements-and-their-function)

Comment: It's a possessive adjective, not pronoun.

Comment: It's a subject noun phrase and it's marked as a possessive. I don't think that makes it an adjective. Subjects don't modify their verbs.

Comment: You should read the chapter gerund in a grammar.

Comment: @rogermue I don't get you, I had never seen such construction

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth thanks your answer is very helpful

Comment: A grammar is a tool as necessary as a dictionary. A pity that a lot of learners try to learn a foreign language without using a grammar. Perhaps the fault of schools which don't teach the use of a grammar.

Comment: @rogermue I don't have a grammar, could you recommend me one?

Comment: It is difficult to recommend grammars. I assume you are Spanish, so an English-Spanish grammar would be recommendable. Have a look at bookshops or amazon. There are English-English grammars, too. I can recommend John Eastwood, Oxford Guide to English Grammar. I would not recommend CGEL, the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. Not appropriate for learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In school I was taught that gerunds take a possessive pronoun and that's that. But it kind of makes sense if you consider that by definition a gerund is a present participle masquerading as a noun. If we substitute an actual noun, we might get something like, "your disturbance [of] me at lunchtime." The subjective "you" would never fit in this construct, and thinking of "bothering" as a noun should help make this rule clear.

Comment: I've been reading *The Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language* and I have the concept clearer, and your answer makes it even more.