# Resulted in "him" or "his" losing the job?

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence,

> *Shortly thereafter he had a car accident which resulted in **him** losing the job.*

My supervisor wanted to change *him* to *his* saying something about gerunds. I disagreed and proved it to her by showing her a GrammarCheck I had done on the sentence. She didn't like it but she let it go.

Isn't using *him* correct in that sentence?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive pronoun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/) Also [Possessive + gerund + object pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217330/), [Usage of the gerund preceded by the possessive pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6756/), and doubtless many more.

Comment: It's certainly grammatical to use *him* here, and possibly preferable in conveying that *losing the job* happened *to him* rather than being an outcome that was effected *by him*.  That said, if your supervisor is willing to let it go, take it silently as a win for your point of view.