# suggest his / him Ving

Tags: gerunds

I'd like to know your judgments on the following sentences. Are they 
well-formed?

1. Mary suggested him buying a laptop.
2. Mary suggested his buying a laptop.
3. What did Mary suggest him buying?
4. What did Mary suggest his buying?
5. What did Mary suggest buying?

Next, consider the following:

8. Mary suggested him going to Boston.
9. Mary suggested his going to Boston.
10. Where did Mary suggest him going?
11. Where did Mary suggest his going?
12. Where did Mary suggest going?

I am considering whether there is a transitive vs. intransitive asymmetry between 1 and 2 on the one hand and 8 and 9 on the other; and between 3 and 4 on the one hand and 10 and 11 on the other.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: 5 and 12 are good, the rest are not.  You don't "suggest someone V-ing", you "suggest that someone V": *What did Mary suggest that he buy?*  and *Mary suggested that he buy a laptop.*  (When there is no third party involved, you can "suggest V-ing".)

Comment: I don’t have a problem with 2 and 9 either.

Comment: @Jim Do you find 4 and 11 acceptable too?

Comment: @Apollyon - No. 4 and 11 sound wrong.

Comment: I suppose I could accept 11 by making it into 9. But it changes it from your intended meaning: “*Mary suggested his going to Boston.” “Oh, where did Mary suggest his going?” “She was in Macy’s when she suggested his going.*”

Comment: All those ings are wrong. She suggested he buy or go. **suggest cannot be followed by a pronoun like that**. That would be French. lui suggérer etc. Only by a bare infinitive or gerund.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["...his parents' dream of \*him\* achieving a Cambridge degree." What is the function of "him" here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94235/his-parents-dream-of-him-achieving-a-cambridge-degree-what-is-the-funct) // 'Suggest [an idea, etc]' (eg 'I suggest you go to Rhyl on Sunday'; 'I suggest a holiday for us all') is certainly licensed, as one can suggest an idea. With POSS-ing it is very formal.