# Does "suggest" + another verb go with an object or subject pronoun?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, syntactic-analysis, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case

I've found this phrase in an English grammar book: "She suggested us going there."

Is it right? I'd say: "She suggested going there to us" or "She suggested we go there" etc ... but I would never say "suggest us".

Comment: As a Brit, it doesn't sound right to me, although you can say "She suggested [that] we go there." What grammar book?

Comment: You hear that a lot in informal usage.  In a formal sense you're right; with "....us going there" , "us" is the (direct) object of "suggested" and  "going there" is a dangling gerund. There are a half-dozen different ways to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Analysing clause elements and their function](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94235/analysing-clause-elements-and-their-function)

Comment: @Spencer That dealt with situations where both ACC-ing and POSS-ing structures were available. The question here is whether that is true after _suggest_.

Comment: What's the rest of the sentence? "She suggested us going there now saves us coming back tomorrow."

Comment: @Mick I could only countenance *She suggested us going there was a bad idea.*

Answer (score 4):

[Melanie](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/how-to-use-the-english-verb-suggest/) provides some of the following on her website (heavily revised here):

> **Suggest** means mention or recommend something to think about, or
> something someone should do. You suggest a thought or an idea.
>
> Suggest is an English verb with restrictions on the types of objects it will
> take. It is not used with two objects, one direct and one indirect,
> though it can be used with one direct object and a to-phrase. It is not used with object + to + infinitive. And some other verbs behave differently, as shown below.
>
> For example, these sentences are NOT correct:
>
> *The company suggested us to take an extra day off.
>
> [unlike *The company advised us to take an extra day off.*]
>
> *I hope you suggest us a good hotel.
>
> (*I hope you can recommend us a good hotel.* is becoming colloquially
> acceptable.)
>
> *In what way are these sentences incorrect?*
>
> **Don’t** use me, us, you, etc. (indirect object pronouns) after suggest.
>
> **Don’t** use an infinitive after suggest.

(The perhaps unpredictable behaviour of 'suggest' *has* been covered before on ELU, but *not* the prohibition on the use of object pronouns, as far as I have been able to discover.)

The one relevant counterexample from [this Google page](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22suggested+us%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=ygNlWKGDJNPowAK7vauACA)

> Everything started when our friend and neighbor Jorge Pang, back in
> the year 2002, suggested us that we gather to practice what we learned
> in the course of healing, which the tree of us had assisted

is not a great recommendation. Admittedly, some less unattractive examples may be found, but I'd say that they are non-standard.

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suggested+him+to%2Csuggested+to+him+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuggested%20him%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuggested%20to%20him%20to%3B%2Cc0), the form *suggested **to** him to [do something]* has been in steep decline for over a century. Superficially, *suggested him to* has always been around, but I get the impression most/all of the earlier instances feature the surviving ***to*** as a preposition, but many/most later ones are non-native speakers using it as an infinitive marker.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Melanie loves teaching English, dancing, and maple syrup, possibly in that order. Why are we supposed to pay attention to her?

Answer (score 1):

The *OED* records a number of meanings for *suggest* dating from 1526. For none of those do the historical examples provide a ditransitive usage, i.e, an instance in which the verb takes two objects. Thus as noted in another answer

> **[1a]** *Can you suggest us a good hotel?

is ungrammatical. It takes a prepositional phrase to rescue 1a:

> **[1b]** Can you suggest a good hotel ***to*** [or ***for*** or in earlier usage, *unto*] us.

However, *suggest* has a history of meaning "put forth for consideration as a candidate", which the *OED* finds first in Macaulay's *History of England*.  In this case the verb can take an objective pronoun for a person to be considered. From [*Parties and Elections in Corporate America*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Fp-HAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22suggest%20him%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22suggest%20him%22) by H L Reiter (1993):

> "At that decisive time, friends of senator Harding will **suggest him**. In fact, I think I might **suggest him** myself."

or an infinitive to indicate the action for consideration. From the report of the [*Royal Commission on the Railway Conciliation Scheme of 1907*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_skmAQAAMAAJ&q=%22suggest%20to%20go%22&dq=%22suggest%20to%20go%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK-8icm5rRAhWr44MKHckOAHMQ6AEILTAD):

> I do not think that my question to you was that you should give me all the names that you would **suggest to go** on that panel.

Comment: As far as I can tell, deadrat considers it hard to imagine that personal details would interest anyone. Why is that a better recommendation than Melanie's? 'Suggest meaning "bring to mind" is not ditransitive' is essentially a more formal paraphrase of 'Don’t use _me, us, you_, etc. (indirect object pronouns) after suggest.'  Why does this not require corroborating references? Melanie is better than nothing.

Comment: For those who missed the reference, "Hard to imagine it would interest anyone" appears as the *About me* information under my nym in my profile on this site. And it means that it's hard to imagine that anyone would be interested in *my* personal details. Melanie tells us she's gonna explain how to use the word *suggest*  "properly". She misses an important usage. Melanie tells us not to use objective personal pronouns or infinitives after *suggest*. Both usages are common and grammatical.  Melanie tells us that *suggest* is an "unusual English verb". It's not. [con't->]

Comment: [<-con't] Melanie claims that *suggest* is not used "the same way that other verbs are". It's used in the same way as other monotransitive verbs. Melanie has a free e-book and will email you free English lessons. She's worth exactly as much as she charges, which is the same weight as her opinion should carry on English usage, the dance, and the reduced sap of *Acer saccharum*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You want corroborating references to prove a negative? Fine, I've given it my best effort. I hope that's sufficient unto the day without my opinions on dance and maple syrup.

Comment: A good answer now. I've helped Melanie out a bit. But, as you say, trying to prove negatives can be rather sticky.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not as good as yours, which I've upvoted for your attributing to Melanie your own vastly-improved version. What part is hers? The articles and prepositions?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Melanie's has become my favorite English language website. I'm just about convinced it's a parody site. Do you know why writing is important. Because it's "how you communicate your thoughts and ideas for someone to read"! Thoughts *and* ideas. And reading! Check out her admonitions on when not to use the definite article, for example with names of lakes (like the Great Salt Lake), mountains (like the Matternhorn), and corporations (the Corporation for Public Broadcasting). I absolutely *love* Melanie. Thanks.

Comment: The driveby downvoter, a plague on this site, has struck again. Is this answer wrong? Or merely lacking? Or did you just misunderstand it? We (including the OP) will never know as you lack the courtesy to inform us.