# Is "Wanting" a Gerund or Present Participle?

Tags: gerunds, present-participles

The conversation eventually makes its way around to him **wanting** to switch and do something new.

Is "wanting" in the sentence considered as a gerund or present participle?

Comment: Trad grammar calls it a gerund, functioning as predicator in the clause _him wanting to switch and do something new_, functioning as complement to the preposition "to". But nowadays we don't usually distinguish present participles and gerunds, but simply call both _ing_ forms 'gerund-participles'. Thus _him wanting to switch and do something new_ is a gerund-participial clause.  "Want" is a catenative verb and the coordination of  infinitival clauses _to switch_ and _do something new_ are its catenative complements.

Comment: @BillJ: Speak for yourself, please. ***We*** do not all follow your terminological habits, and they are by no means general.

Comment: @JohnLawler I could say the same to you. My terminology is based on H&P's award-winning CGEL, the leading grammar today, not on some long-out-dated grammar.

Comment: CGEL is a good grammar, but hardly standard. Nor all that new, either. Big, though, I'll grant you. I follow McCawley, which is about the same vintage, though not quite so voluminous. We all, of course, have own own favorite terms, and our own [publications](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LawlerPublications.html) show how we use them.

Comment: Plus ça change.... Possible duplicate of [When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive adjective/determiner?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner) (though ['his parents dream of him achieving a Cambridge degree ...'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94235/his-parents-dream-of-him-achieving-a-cambridge-degree-what-is-the-funct) is closer).

Answer (score 2):

The clause

- *him wanting to switch and do something new*

is a gerund complement, a noun clause that is the object of the preposition *to*,
which in turn is part of the idiomatic construction

- *make its way around to*.

The subject of the gerund clause is *him* (it could also be *his*; both are correct),
and the gerund verb is of course *wanting* (the verb form of the gerund is the
present participle, not to be confused with participial constructions).

The direct object of *wanting* (gerunds can have direct objects) is another
complement clause, this one made up of two conjoined infinitives:

- *to switch* and *to do something new*.

Answer (score 0):

Labeling *wanting* either a gerund or a participle will get you nowhere.
Instead, all you want to know is that the bracketed portion constitutes a non-finite clause:

> *The conversation eventually makes its way around to* [*him wanting to switch and do something new*].

Comment: who said anything about getting anywhere?  this is not an answer.

Comment: @Toothrot I did, in case you didn't notice. Your answer says it's a gerund and that a gerund is a "substantive," which a dictionary defines as 'a noun or broadly a word or word group functioning syntactically as a noun'. Now, _wanting_ is not a noun or a word functioning syntactically as a noun however broadly you slice it. It's a non-finite verb and the head of the bracketed non-finite clause.

Comment: Which is a noun clause, as noted. Of course _wanting_ is a verb. But folks have been told (even here on ELU.SE) that a gerund is a verb that's being used as a noun. Which is nonsense, of course.

Answer (score -3):

You have a ***participle*** here:

The conversation eventually makes its way around to him wanting to switch and do something new.

= The conversation eventually makes its way around to him, ***who wants*** to switch and do something new.

In case it was a Gerund, the form of the   pronoun would be "his" as the Gerund is a so called "verbal noun".

According to [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/dangling-participles)

"Participles of verbs are often used to introduce subordinate clauses, which give extra information about the main part of a sentence (known as the main clause).

It’s important to use participles in subordinate clauses correctly. 
The participle should always describe an action performed by the subject of the main part of the sentence.

For example:

Mrs Stevens,opening the door quietly,came into the room.
 
In this sentence, the present participle (opening) in the subordinate clause refers to the subject of the main clause.

Mrs Stevens is both opening the door and coming into the room."

Comment: but the conversation does not make its way around to _him;_ it makes its way around to his _wanting_