# What is the meaning of this "my wife insisted on my putting on my thick winter woollies this morning"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of this "my wife insisted on my putting on my thick winter woollies this morning"?
Especially this part "**insisted on my putting** on my thick winter woollies"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["...his parents' dream of \*him\* achieving a Cambridge degree." What is the function of "him" here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94235/his-parents-dream-of-him-achieving-a-cambridge-degree-what-is-the-funct). The POSS-ing construction here sounds starchy and uncomfortable; 'insisted that I put on ...' is more idiomatic.

Comment: Note that "putting" here is a form of the verb "put", not the verb "putt".

Comment: @HotLicks Not that that would actually change the grammar, despite the unusual image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - *My wife insisted on **my** putting on my thick winter woollies this morning.*

This is grammatical, but it's not the only grammatical construction. It could also be said:

- *My wife insisted on **me** putting on my thick winter woollies this morning*.

The gerund phrase can have a subject that's in the possessive (e.g, *my*), or in the objective (*me*). Both work and neither is incorrect; it's a case of speakers' choice.  And from now on, let's dispense with the woollies, OK? Simpler sentences have fewer distractions.

- *She **insisted on me/my wearing** a parka today.*

There are two clauses here. The main clause is about her insisting on something,

- *She insisted on `S`* (where *`S`* represents some clause as object)

*`S`*, the subordinate gerund object complement clause, is about what she insisted on.

- *my wearing a parka today ~ me wearing a parka today*

The confusing point may be the *on*, which is part of the construction *insist on*, winding up right before the *my* that's part of the subordinate clause. They're not really related; *on* is just a part of the verb, like the *at* of *look at*, but *my* is the subject of the subordinate clause and isn't related to *on* at all.