# Grammatical Construction - Name?

Tags: grammar

In my essays I use the constructions like the following once in a while:

> The implications of someone being elected into higher office are far-ranging.

What are sentences that contain constructions like "being elected into higher office" called? Knowing this would help find and study the rules surrounding this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["...his parents' dream of \*him\* achieving a Cambridge degree." What is the function of "him" here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94235/his-parents-dream-of-him-achieving-a-cambridge-degree-what-is-the-funct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Being elected* is a gerund phrase. When expanded to *being elected to higher office* it is still a gerund phrase. Such phrases start with the gerundial form of a verb. See for example:

> [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/gerund-phrase/)
>
> A gerund phrase is a phrase consisting of a gerund and any modifiers or objects associated with it. A gerund is a noun made from a verb root plus ing (a present participle). A whole gerund phrase functions in a sentence just like a noun, and can act as a subject, an object, or a predicate nominative.
>
> "My doctor suggests running to improve my health."

Knowing this may help you compose other prose of the same sort  of construction.

Comment: However, if it's a noun, shouldn't *somebody* be *somebody's*?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes I agree with you entirely, but that would be to start another vein of analysis of the question's quotation.

Comment: OP should realise that this is an ACC-ing construction.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Firstly, why should the OP realise or even know? If they did they wouldn't be asking in the first place. And secondly, what is ACC-ing? I found a linguistics question not dissimilar to the OP's [What kind of phrase is Acc-ing gerund?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/23277/what-kind-of-phrase-is-acc-ing-gerund) and finally I understood that ACC stands for accusative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Many things "should" be in this world but, despite that, they are not. Surely we "should" help and explain rather than prescribe and judge? What is ACC? I find dozens of definitions of this acronym, so why should any OP know about it?

Comment: The primary aim of ELU is to provide a non-bloated, easy-to-search, correct (or showing divided opinion where necessary) repository of English usage. It is not primarily a Q-&-A instant-help service (hence the 'duplicate' CV reason). Here, the structure The implications of [{someone} {being elected into higher office}], which constitutes the essence of this question,  is an ACC-ing structure, covered before on ELU, and easily searchable.

Comment: @Anton Thank you very much for helping me understand this better!

Comment: Thank you Sam. Keep coming here. You will get help, advice, even criticism;  but in general they are all designed to help you and I have found that the site is a good place for reasoned discussion.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Warning: Grammar terms vary.</sub>

*Being elected* is the passive form of the **present participle** *electing*. For example:

> Active: *The implications of voters **electing** somebody are
> far-ranging.*
>
> Passive: *The implications of somebody **being elected** [by voters] are
> far-ranging.*

If you remove the subject (e.g. *voters*) in front of the participles, you can turn them into gerunds (which function like nouns). For example:

> Active: *The implications of **electing** somebody are far-ranging.*
>
> Passive: *The implications of **being elected** are
> far-ranging.*