# Is is right using expressions like "before her coming here" in place of "before she came here"

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

I often use expression like these

> - *I came to this place before him getting here* (rather than using *before
>     he got here*).
> - *We were having a lot of fun before before her getting here* (instead
>     of *before she got here*).

I did not see a lot of results on the web for expressions like these, so I am wondering whether it is right or not?

Comment: Related: [When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive pronoun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-pronoun)

Comment: Both are grammatically "correct", though old-fashioned readers will insist you must use possessive *his* before the gerund (*her* is of course both possessive and objective); @RegDwighт's link will instruct you on the nicer points. However, the construction with the simple past is more natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @StoneyB says, both forms are "valid". But although I don't like admitting to being "old-fashioned", I would much prefer *possessive **his** before the gerund*. Not that it matters much, because like almost all native speakers, I would always use OP's second alternatives.

Since the same construction arises with many verbs, consider these Google Books results...

> [before he saw it](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22before%20he%20fixed%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22before%20he%20saw%20it%22&oq=%22before%20he%20saw%20it%22&gs_l=serp.3...390111.392093.3.392716.8.8.0.0.0.0.107.496.7j1.8.0...0.0...1c.1.m0XqVLW-Ml0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1412&bih=897) 339,000 hits
>
> [before him seeing it](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22before%20he%20fixed%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22before%20him%20seeing%20it%22&oq=%22before%20him%20seeing%20it%22&gs_l=serp.3...4660.9419.4.9737.20.20.0.0.0.0.108.1239.18j2.20.0...0.0...1c.1.oh2_u_w622E&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1412&bih=897) 421 hits
>
> [before his seeing it](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22before%20he%20fixed%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22before%20his%20seeing%20it%22&oq=%22before%20his%20seeing%20it%22&gs_l=serp.3...3679.4046.5.4420.2.2.0.0.0.0.51.98.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.uFmyNBvgzkQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1412&bih=897) 5 hits

So it's understandable OP doesn't *see a lot of results on the web for expressions like these*. They might be "technically valid", but that means nothing if people hardly ever use them.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that it is right in American English. I know from personal experiences of American people and American television programmes, that Americans use wordings such as "We were having a lot of fun before before her getting here".

Comment: Then why does "before him/his getting here" have 6 Google hits, and "before he got here" have millions? This does not seem to be an expression that Americans typically use.

Comment: Peter, I'm not saying the particular expression "before him/his getting here" is typical. I'm saying that saying something such as that, seems to be right in American English. That's why I wrote in my answer "***wordings such as*** "We were having a lot of fun before before her getting here"".

Comment: I would agree that we Americans use a lot of gerund phrases like this, but for some reason the particular expression "before her getting here" sounds strange to me in these sentences.

Comment: @PeterShor You're right: you really do not say that. It is just *before she got her*. The *before her getting here* sounds quite bizarre in almost all conceivable circumstances. And it is not just this verb, either.  You cannot use a gerund like this in any English flavor of my acquaintance.

Comment: I suspect what is going on here is that Americans don't generally use *-ing* gerunds with *before* or *after*. With other prepositions like *with*, they're absolutely fine.

Comment: @PeterShor Can you give me example of what you are suggesting please?

Comment: @Micheal: I'm guessing Peter means Americans are more likely to say ["before I do that I will"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22before+I+do+that+I+will%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) rather than ["before doing that I will"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22before+doing+that+I+will%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Google Books show the first version is twice as common as the second version overall. As a UK speaker, I've no particular preference, but I've no idea if Americans feel the same when comparing the two forms.