# Usage of we instead of us

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar, literary-techniques

> 1. Lest they do anything before **we**.

> 2. Lest they do anything before **us**.

One of my students, for their creative writing coursework, phrased his sentence as shown in quote 1, but I have a confusion as to which (1 or 2) is more grammatically appropriate, and the literary device used in the first sentence, if any.

Comment: Nothing follows it.

Comment: Then *before us.* It follows a preposition

Comment: Related: [Is is right using expressions like “before her coming here” in place of “before she came here”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95095/is-is-right-using-expressions-like-before-her-coming-here-in-place-of-before)

Answer (score 1):

I would say the second one.

The first one seems to lacks a ***do.*** in the end. It should be

> Lest they do anything before we ***do***.

Comment: Please look at the Help Center to see how an answer considered _good_ on ELU should be written. Answers lacking supporting references (linked and attributed) often come across as, and may be, no more than personal opinion (especially when starting 'In my opinion' / 'I would say' etc). There is even the possibility that they're incorrect. Many questions have been answered before on ELU, and this one certainly has.