# to use "their" or "they're" -

Tags: phrases

In this sentence, which one to use and why:

He is not going to change his practices based on (their)(they're) being unpresidential.

Comment: The contraction "they're" is a short form of the words "they are"; so if you replace "they're" with "they are" in any sentence where "they're" properly occurs, the resulting wording should make sense. (And if it doesn't make sense, "they're" was not the right spelling in the first place.)

Comment: @SvenYargs People, Read the question again.

Comment: @神秘德里克: I understand the question, and I know how to determine whether _they're_ or _their_ is correct. My previous comment was an attempt to suggest a method that Rebecca can use on this and future occasions to determine whether _they're_ is the right choice—regardless of whether the _they_ in a particular instance refers to people, subatomic particles, or abstract arguments.

Comment: Rebecca, Sven Yargs is wholly correct and you'll find more help for Questions like that at English Language Learners…

Comment: Only "their" is correct here. See the similar question [Was “their being followed” replaced by “they're being followed” over the years?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105914/was-their-being-followed-replaced-by-theyre-being-followed-over-the-years) for more information about this construction.

Answer (score 2):

It is most certainly ***their***

> #### He is not going to change his practices based on their being unpresidential.

**Their** is the possessive of **they** and they're is a shorter form of "they are"

The sentence here refer's to the idealogy of a "group" of people and the sentence above cannot permit "they're" in any possible manner as it collapses the core value of the sentence.

Just remember the simple trick - *They're* is nothing but a shorter way of saying *They are*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's their. `they're` forms a clause, which leads to the need of some leading words like `based on that they're ...` or `based on the fact that they're ...`.

Comment: 神秘德里克 can you explain a useful difference between "… based on (their)(they're) being unpresidential" and "based on that they're ... or based on the fact that they're"?