# Gerund preceded by a genitive?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives, gerunds

Is this sentence actually grammatical?

> You know **your** having a rough day when kittens don't even make you smile.

The writer of this sentence may intend to mean *you're* instead of *your* but I'm just wondering if having a gerund preceded by a genitive is considered grammatical in this case.

If the sentence above is ungrammatical, why is this sentence grammatical?

> He resents your being more popular than he is.

What's the difference between these two sentence that determines one to be grammatical and the other to be not?

This is how I analyze the two sentences and I can't see the difference:

1. "*You know **it** when kittens don't even make you smile*" for
   "***it***" = "*your having a rough day*"
2. "*He resents **it***" for "***it***" = "*your being more popular
   than he is*"

Comment: No. It should be *you're*.  This mistake is being made at an alarming rate among today's youth.  However, in the sentence, "Your having a rough day has no bearing on my decision to hand out homework." is grammatical.

Comment: Related if not a dupe: [When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive pronoun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-pronoun)

Answer (score 4):

It's grammatically incorrect: "You know **you're** having a rough day when kittens don't even make you smile" is what was meant. It was either a typo, a thinko, or just another ignoramus expressing itself.

That said, however, it is possible to say something like this:

> **Your having a bad day** is not going to ruin my day.

Some native speakers might write and say it this way:

> **You having a bad day** is not going to ruin my day.

Now that you've added a question, I'll add more of an answer.

If you want to make the first sentence grammatical without changing "*your*" to "*you're*", it has to be something like this:

> You know (that) your having a rough day **is true** when kittens don't even make you smile.

The syntax of the sentence is different. In the sentence immediately above, *your having a rough day* is a gerund clause that serves as the subject of a subordinate clause because it is preceded by **[that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementizer)**, what Linguistics Professor John Lawler calls a [complementizer](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAComplementizer.htm), which means that it requires a predicate: a verb and what some people would call a subject complement. I don't want to dwell on terminology, because it isn't always agreed upon, even by professional linguists (I'm not a professional linguist).

In your original example and your added analysis, the verb and subject complement are missing, but it's not grammatically possible to do that **in this case** by eliding them from the sentence. If you had given us this instead:

> Your having a rough day is clear. You know it when kittens don't even make you smile.

then you can say *"it" = "your having a rough day"*, because *it* is a pronoun that refers back to the first sentence.

The gerund clause is a noun phrase. If I substitute another noun phrase, e.g.,:

> You know **giraffes** when kittens don't even make you smile.

you should be able to see that something is wrong because the sentence is incomplete, not elided. I can change it to:

> You know **giraffes are evil** when kittens don't even make you smile.

Now it's a grammatical sentence, but it's semantically unacceptable because it's totally illogical.

To make the other new sentence simpler, let's change it to this:

> He resents (you/your) being more popular.

or

> He resents (you/your) having a good day.

If:

> A: I'm having a good day.
>   B: I know it. (*it* = *you are having a good day*) But John resents it. (***it*** = ***the fact*** that you are having a good day)

I can say:

> 1: I resent your being more popular.

just as I can say:

> 2: I resent giraffes.

but I must say:

> 3: I resent (it) **that** ***you are*** more popular.

Comment: +1 Heh, that's too funny.  (see my comment)

Comment: Thank you. It would be greater if you can answer my second question.

Comment: @Jim: Yes, I saw your comment after answering the question. Which provides evidence that there are some things that native speakers do agree on. :-)

Comment: @Curious- In the first, "your" is a contraction of "you are".  In the second it's a possessive pronoun.

Comment: @Curious: I apologize for the verbosity of this answer. I'm not a professional linguist. Someone like Prof. Lawler or jlovegren (both linguists who post here) can do a much better, clearer, simpler, and briefer job of explaining the syntactic and grammatical differences. If what I've added isn't helpful, please let me know and I'll delete it. I don't have any more time to spend on it, I'm afraid. But it's an interesting question, so I hope someone can provide a better answer.

Comment: That makes me wonder (sorry, I've only just stumbled upon this question): the way that helps analyse such statements is by saying them from the other person's perspective, so I instead of you and you instead of I. Clearly "This is you're mess" doesn't make sense, translating into "This is I'm mess". Instead: "This is your mess" -> "This is my mess". This is fine, too: "You having a bad day is not going to ruin my day" -> "Me having a bad day is not going to ruin your day". But this one i have a problem with: "Your having a bad day is not going to ruin my day" as it translates into [CONTINUED]

Comment: ... "My having a bad day is not going to ruin your day" - how does that make sense? Does "having a bad day" have a role of a noun, meaning something like "fact that I'm/you're having a bad day" or "state of having a bad day"? This comment is a bit long, I know. Maybe I should have posted a new question?