# Meaning of "my having completed my packing"

Tags: word-usage, gerunds, past-participles

I ran into this in a novel:

> This expedition began this morning almost an hour later than I had planned, despite my having completed my packing, and loaded the Ford with all necessary items well before eight o’clock.

I suppose "despite my having completed my packing" equals "although I had completed my packing". I would like to know if there is a rule for *despite* + *possessive adj* + *having* + *p.p.*. If so, any links would be appreciated so that I could study more on it.

Comment: It's *packing* not *packaging*.

Comment: It's perfectly ordinary, exactly like any other gerund clause acting as object of any other preposition. Perhaps you are confused by the fact that the gerund in question is the auxiliary *have* and is complemented by the past participle, forming a perfect construction. But compare "I got away early **by** having completed my packing well before eight o'clock."

Comment: Susan, thanks a lot for your edition of my words, they are clearer now:)

Comment: Jim, thx for pointing that misspell out

Comment: Susan, besides You taught me some good points in producing the tongue, thx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've encountered a perfectly ordinary sentence, which uses a verb (to have) as a gerund.
A gerund, of course is a verb form that acts as a noun, and thus it is used as an object in a sentence. The possessive personal noun is used to specify whose action it is we're talking about.

Compare:

> despite having done everything to avoid it, I was fined a hefty sum.

Now this would imply that *I* would "have done everything to avoid it", as opposed to

> despite my friends having done everything...

In your case, the character is taking part in an expedition of sorts, so the use of *my having completed my packing* makes it clear that the expedition was delayed *not* because of him/her being late.

A couple of links:

- [A Canadian one](http://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/bien-well/fra-eng/grammaire-grammar/possessif-possessive-eng.html)
- [A vaguely related question on this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-pronoun)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Elias. your answer is useful. I enjoyed the links you introduced.