# In «In addition to *his being a great writer*,» what is «his being a great writer»?

Tags: gerunds, parts-of-speech

Is that a gerund-like construction? A noun phrase? What kind of part of speech is that? I apologize in advance if there is some thread that already deals with this issue, but since I don't really know the name, I didn't know where to look.
Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

It's a verb phrase whose head is a present participle which is being treated as a noun in the context of the greater sentence. Which is very the definition of a gerund, yes. So "his being a great writer" is a *gerund clause*, in which "his" marks the *subject*. (Whether that subject is to be marked using a genitive or an accusative pronoun is actually an interesting question, but it has been addressed in great detail [elsewhere on this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-pronoun).)