# I appreciate you(r) noticing this

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I often use the pattern 'I appreciate your noticing this' but recently decided it sounds strange, and switched to 'you'. (I do this with different verbs; this is just an example.) Are they both valid?

Comment: Either one is OK. The subject of a [gerund complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf) may appear either in possessive form (_your, his, Mr. Smith's_ -- this is called a `POSS_-ing_` gerund complement), or in an objective (originally accusative) form (_you, him, Mr. Smith_ -- this is called an `ACC_-ing_` gerund complement). There is no grammatical difference.

Comment: Traditionally, *your* is preferred by style books (i.e. the possessive of any personal pronoun). With regular nouns, it's more complicated.

Comment: There can be a semantic difference. The audience didn't appreciate your singing those bawdy songs / The throat specialist didn't want you singing.

Comment: See the [excellent answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2628/300) on the linked question.

Comment: Thanks, guys, very helpful comments and now I know how to describe the general version of this. To the person that downvoted the question, without comment, 30 seconds after posting: please forgive me if my expression of gratitude is less effusive.