# What is the origin of the progressive

Tags: language-evolution

What is the origin of the progressive form of the english verbs

Comment: @RegDwight The linked question addresses the origin of the *-ing* form, but says nothing about what is asked here. The origin of the progressive constructions in which that form is used is, I believe, a matter of some controversy; and the elaboration and use of those constructions is a process which is still in progress.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_and_progressive_aspects#Origin) suggests it may be borrowed from Celtic. That would explain why German doesn't have a progressive construction -- no Celts to calque.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's one theory; against it lies the fact that the progressive seems to have arisen first in Late Old English, in the North: a time and place when the principal external influence on spoken English would have been Norse rather than British. Another theory is that it was originally a literary form which arose under the influence of Latin. At any rate, it took a long time to become grammaticalized: it was not common until the 16th century, its forms were not completed until the early part of the 19th; and it is still evolving in AAVE and Caribbean dialects.

Comment: [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2625/24489) class handout has a deeper treatment and a bibliography.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely is still evolving and has many regional and social variants. Between around 1850 and 1925 or so in the US, sentences like _The bridge is building_ gave way to _The bridge is being built_ for the same meaning -- "Under Construction". The change regularized the separation of the patient subject _bridge_ as due to Passive, and the active participle _building_ as due to the Progressive. So one can now call it a Passive Progressive, in form as well as function. A lot of syntactic changes go in this regularization direction. Same as _ain't_, but that went too far.