# Interested in him learning French - with accusative 'him'

Tags: grammaticality, british-english, gerunds, grammatical-case

Good morning everyone!

Is it correct to say " I' m interested in him learning French in the future"?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Why do you think it might not be?

Comment: Because after having read it aloud a couple of times it somehow sounded not proper English to me, although I was sure it was grammatically correct.

Comment: In case you're wondering, [nohat's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2628/18696) at the linked question includes "['grammar tips' often confuse] informal style with incorrect grammar, a common problem in grammar advice. The versions of the examples with accusative instead of genitive (e.g. What do you think about him buying such an expensive car?) are perfectly grammatical and simply a less stuffy style."

Comment: @AndrewLeach I agree that Nohat's superb answer there deals adequately with this OP's question. However, the OP's question and the one Nohat answered are mutually exclusive (one asking about the possessive, the other the accusative pronoun). Might it be an idea to modify the OQ so that readers looking for the answer to this question can get there directly ... ?