# possessive-before-gerund: "him sleeping with" or "his sleeping with"?

Tags: possessives, gerunds

> Did gypsies cut off man's penis in revenge for *him* sleeping with one of their girlfriends?

Shouldn't that be *his* sleeping?

Is the possessive-before-gerund rule still a rule on both sides of the Big Pond, or only on the left side?

Would anyone care about grammar while reading this headline?

[Ouch!](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2580115/Did-gypsies-cut-Middlesbrough-mans-penis-revenge-Police-search-A66-missing-manhood.html#ixzz3KMhJZtdt)

Comment: There are other use cases that are just as effective. Why not try another?

Comment: It should be **a** *man's penis*

Comment: @Mari-LouA Of course, it should be.

Comment: This is a case where I can heartily recommend [the previous duplicate answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2628/15299), by @nohat.