# Which of these two sentences is correct?

Tags: pronouns

1. I don't like YOU leaving early.
2. I don't like YOUR leaving early.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  April Fools.

Answer (score -1):

Well, in formal terms the 2nd is the correct one:

> [Barron's Pocket Guide to Correct English](https://books.google.ca/books?id=zbwsFf9wIDUC&pg=PA20&dq=%22don%27t%20like%20your%20leaving%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xOMaVe_-AfX_sASS8oKAAg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22don%27t%20like%20your%20leaving%22&f=false) - Page 20 Michael Temple -
>   2004
>
> WRONG: I don't like you leaving early.
>
> RIGHT I don't like your
>   leaving early.

However, the first is accepted in informal speech or writing and has a slightly different meaning:

*I don't like that you're leaving early.*

Also, have a look at [the previous thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-pronoun) referred in an answer.