# What type of pronoun shoould I use before a gerund?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, pronouns

While reviewing grammar, I came upon this sentence:
"I was able to inspect the apartment without his noticing the movement of my eyes."

However, this phrasing seems awkward, especially the "his".
I feel like one of the following two changes would be more grammatical:

> I was able to inspect the apartment without *him* noticing the movement of my eyes.
>
> I was able to inspect the apartment without *his* noticing of the movement of my eyes.

Are either of these two more "correct"? Or are there any other better changes?

Comment: I cannot explain why, but to me the first sentence, with "him", sounds correct. The second might be too, but if it is, it's a very awkward construction.

Comment: This reference may be helpful RE: gerunds and possessive pronouns: http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/gerundspro.html

Comment: I would say *I was able to inspect the apartment without his noticing the movement of my eyes,* but both of yours are also correct.

Comment: [When must a gerund be preceded by a possessive pronoun as opposed to an accusative one?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253181/when-must-a-gerund-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-pronoun-as-opposed-to-an-accusati)

Comment: Where a gerund-participial clause is complement of a preposition, a personal pronoun subject can be genitive (his) or accusative (him); both are fine. It all boils down to style with the genitive being more formal than the accusative. It's as simple as that!