# "I understand him going back there"

Tags: gerunds, present-participles

I heard a sportscaster say this. Since gerunds are preceded by possessive pronouns, this would have to be a present participle. (him, who is going back). 
I do think, however, that the gerund (his going back) would have been more appropriate. Can someone tell whether this is wrong usage, gerunds are preceded by objective pronouns in informal speech, or why he chose him here. Can you use the objective to put emphasis on the person rather than the action itself? I am aware of the fact that some might be annoyed by my repeated questions regarding this topic but I have not been able to answer this despite having looked at various sources, covering this topic.

Comment: This has been asked before. Read the answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2628/300).

Comment: So by *caster* are you referring to a magician in some role-playing game or is there another definition capable of speech of which I am unaware?

Comment: The person, commentating a sports event, commonly referred to as the games caster.

Comment: @L.White- Wow.  I've never heard that one before.  I've always heard, *sportscaster*, *commentator*, *play-by-play commentator/announcer* etc, but it never occurred to me that it could be shortened to just *caster*.  Interesting.  Where are you from?

Comment: I'm just trying to get my head around this concept of a sportscaster who's a language expert.

Comment: The editing is bad. I orginally put a dot after this. It was never meant to be the sportcasters statement but rather the conclusion I made after.