# preposition + genitive vs non-genitive subjects + gerund

Tags: prepositions, gerunds, possessive-pronouns, gerund-phrases

I was wondering which of the following phrases are correct?

"without their having to learn" or "without them having to learn"?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner

Comment: @AlanCarmack, I actually went through that thread, but was not able to figure out an answer to my question. I'll appreciate it if you explain it a little bit.

Comment: What *specifically* were you not able to figure out? In almost all contexts it makes absolutely no difference whether you use possessive+gerund or noun subject+verb, but at least one answer points out that [When the possessive alternative is used, it focuses attention on the action described in the ‘-ing’ clause. In contrast the regular Noun Phrase form puts more emphasis on the person doing the action.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/42750/2637) Which might *occasionally* be accurate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, do you mean "without them having to learn" is wrong?

Comment: What makes you think I have any opinion about "right/wrong" here? I just said *in almost all contexts it makes absolutely no difference*. In fact, the possessive form is [still far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=without+my+having+to%2Cwithout+me+having+to&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwithout%20my%20having%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithout%20me%20having%20to%3B%2Cc0), but arguably you might sound more "modern" if you opt for the straight noun subject version.

Comment: When a gerund-participle clause is complement of a preposition (like "without") both genitive and non-genitive subjects are possible.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you mentioned that "you use possessive+gerund or noun subject+verb". I think this means "without their having to learn". But in "without them having to learn", I have used an Objective Pronoun (them). That's why I thought it might be wrong.

Comment: @BillJ, I am so sorry for my lack of English knowledge. I'll appreciate it if you define genitive and non-genitive subjects means.

Comment: Sorry, "their" is genitive, and "them" is non-genitive.

Comment: @BillJ, Thank you so much. Would you please add your comment as an answer here? I think this is the accepted answer.

Comment: A bit late, but I've posted an answer.

Comment: @user2521204: I think it's pretty clear from your comments that you would do better asking questions on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Responses there are tailored to meet the needs of learners and non-native speakers, whereas ELU targets [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts.](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you so much for your comment. I actually was not aware of that site. However, now I have my answer. I'll post my future questions to that website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where a gerund-participle clause is complement to a preposition, both genitive and non-genitive subjects are possible:

*I have no objections to [their/them taking notes].*

*She insisted on [my/me being present at the interview]*.

So, both your examples are fine. It's essentially a free choice between genitive "their" and non-genitive "them", though the genitive is fairly formal compared to the non-genitive.

Note that if a non-genitive subject is a personal pronoun, it always takes the accusative case ("me/him/her/us/them").

Comment: Would you please explain your last paragraph a little more. Thanks.

Comment: Sure: if the subject is a personal pronoun, it can be the genitive "my/your/his/her/our/your/their", or the accusative "me/him/her/us/them", but not the nominative "I/he/she/we/they".