# Is the pronoun "us" grammatical in: "it is worth us examining"

Tags: grammar, british-english, syntactic-analysis, formality

Is it grammatically incorrect to add "us" in this sentence or should it be removed?

> Strong arguments exist in support of both sides which implies it is worth **us** examining both points of view before drawing any conclusions.

Comment: It's traditional to use the possessive with a gerund: *it is worth our examining.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive adjective/determiner?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner)

Comment: What research did you do that led you to believe that might be a problem?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence seems very formal, like part of a research paper or report. With that, no "us" is the most appropriate. Texts like these are typically better off without personal pronouns. "it is worth examining..." But, I don't know the context of your passage.

Further, I would rephrase the sentence:

> Strong arguments exist in support of both sides, implying it is worth 
>   examining both points of view before drawing any conclusions.

Answer (score -1):

You should write "It is worth our examination." This answer is correct because it sounds more sophisticated.

Comment: How is “sounding more sophisticated” proof of correctness?