# "Synyster Gates/Gates' being left handed"

Tags: possessives

I texted a friend "I was wrong about Synyster Gates being left handed" earlier this morning, and I realized that I don't know if the word "being" here is something Gates possesses, or if it is a verb. I am leaning toward it being something Gates possesses.

Which sentence is correct?
"I was wrong about Synyster Gates being left handed."
Or "I was wrong about Synyster Gates' being left handed?"

Also, I couldn't find a previously asked question about this topic, but please point me to it by providing a link if there is one.

Comment: you may mean sinister gates.

Comment: I think your question may be answered here: [When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive adjective/determiner?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner) You can use either form.