# What is the meaning of the " 's " in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I'm currently studying to pass the TOEFL test with a high score, but I have encountered a sentence in an app that I fail to see why it is correct:
"The committee members resented the president's not informing them of the meeting."
Can someone explain to me how the mentioned sentence works?

Comment: Hello, gishki. This question is a possible duplicate of [When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive adjective/determiner?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner). // You may wish to learn that 'I have encountered a sentence in an app that I fail to see why it is correct' is incorrect. It's difficult to rephrase; I'd use  'I have come across/encountered a sentence in an app that is giving me concern; I fail to see why it is correct'. You could look up ["Ross constraint" + violation]....

Comment: Some might insist on a look at "misplaced modifiers" as well. They might insist on  'In an app, I have come across/encountered a sentence that is giving me concern; I fail to see why it is correct'.

Answer (score -1):

The title of your question refers only to the "'s" in the sentence, so I am going to explain this.

This is a common genitive. So, *the president's* is the genitive (possessive) to the gerund construction *not informing them*. The question is "*Whose* not informing them?", and the answer is "the president's".
The confusing part may be the word *not*, but just think of dropping it:

> The committee members resented the president's informing them of the meeting.

The construction *not informing them* is a gerund, that is a construction derived from a verb (*to inform*) that is used as subject or object, as in:

> **Sailing** is fun. (subject position)
>
> I enjoy **singing**. (object position)

The original sentence (which has the gerund in object position) could be rephrased in a subclause (taking care of the tense then):

> The commitee member resented that the president had not informed them of the meeting.

Comment: I think this answer might benefit from including (and explaining) the word *gerund* somewhere.

Comment: This is all correct, but it somehow misses the crux of the confusion, namely that _the subject of a gerund is (often, though not always) in the possessive_.

Comment: I expanded the answer at the beginning to say inother words what I wrote beforehand, hope this makes it clear.