# Gerund usage in sentences

Tags: gerunds

The other day, I read this sentence " I don't like your bossing me around".
I was wondering if this sentence should be " I don't like you bossing me around". Shouldn't be?

Would you please explain it to me?

Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: Both are fine, It's a free choice, though the former with "your" is a little more formal.

Comment: This issue has been dealt with several times on this site. You will find a good discussion here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner

Comment: Please don't put spaces after quotation marks