# He doesn't like me/my spending time with her

Tags: gerunds

What should precede a gerund in a sentence ?
A possessive pronoun or object pronoun.
For eg:- He doesn't like me/my spending time with her.
Which, out of me and my,is correct ?

Comment: Have you researched this issue? It is dealt with pretty extensively on this site and elsewhere.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner.

Comment: Thanks, Xanne !

Comment: Here (in everyday conversation, one assumes), the ACC-ing structure is sounding increasingly pretentious as the years pass by. Though neither is ungrammatical, and as both mean very much the same in this example, you'd almost always hear _me_ used by native speakers.